# como salvar escolha do usuario dentro um modal nav-tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, django, modal

Tenho um modal com algumas abas referente a fechamento de conta, eu preciso salvar as escolhas do usuário, eu carrego tipos de pagamentos, tipo de bandeiras etc, cada botão pode ter um id, esse id que quero salvar, só não sei onde colocar.
Na ultima aba vou dar um submit e preciso saber todas as escolhas do usuário, por exemplo: DEBITO > REDE> VISA.
Só que não sei como armazenar isso pelo Django.
Alguém já trabalhou em alguma lógica parecida ?

```html
<div id="card_pos_modal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:80%">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a  href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">TIPO DE CARTÃO</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a  href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">ADQUIRENTE</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a  href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">BANDEIRA</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a  href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab">VALOR</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content ">

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                                {% for method in methodpay %}
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg method" >{{ method.methodpay_short_name method.id }}</button>
                                </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                                {% for acquire in acquirer %}
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg acquirer" >{{ acquire.acquirer_short_name acquire.id }}</button>
                                </div>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action='' method="POST">
                                {% for mode in modepay %}
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg mode" >{{ mode.payment_short_name mode.id }}</button>
                                </div>

                                {% endfor %}
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action="{% url 'insert_value' %}"  method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <center>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <input id="value_insert_n" name="insert_value" type="number" step="0.010" style="width:250px;font-size: 40px" autofocus>
                                </div>
                                    </center>
                                <center>
                                    <label><input id="typepay_code" name="typepay_code" value="{{ typepay_code }}" type="hidden"></label>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >OK</button>
                                </center>

                            </form>
                            <div class="modal-footer">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma é criando campos ocultos (`type="hidden"`) dentro do último form (o form que sofrerá o submit). Cada campo input terá um `name` correspondente a cada opção dos botões clicados nas abas anteriores:

```
<input type="hidden" name="method">
<input type="hidden" name="acquirer">
<input type="hidden" name="mode">
```

Feito isso, adicione uma classe qualquer (uma classe que não seja usada em nenhum lugar) em cada botão das 3 primeiras abas (por exemplo, coloquei a classe `.opts_`) e coloque também dois atributos `data-*`, um com o `id` da opção e outro que identifique o tipo da opção. Por exemplo, nos botões da primeira aba, coloquei:

```
<button type="button" data-id="COLOQUE AQUI O ID" data-btn="method"
class="btn btn-info btn-lg method opts_" >{{ method.methodpay_short_name method.id }}</button>
```

Onde tem `COLOQUE AQUI O ID` você irá colocar o id gerado pelo backend. Repare que no atributo `data-btn` coloquei o valor `method`. Esse valor serve para agrupar os botões dessa aba. Em cada aba você irá alterar o valor do `data-btn`. Por exemplo, na segunda aba, os botões terão o valor `data-btn="acquirer"`. Esses valores irão referenciar os names dos inputs hidden do último form.

Então acrescente um código JavaScript que irá jogar o valor do `data-id` do botão clicado no respectivo input hidden do último form:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var opts_ = document.querySelectorAll(".opts_");
   for(let el of opts_){
      el.onclick = function(){
         document.querySelector("[name='"+this.dataset.btn+"']").value = this.dataset.id;
      }
   }
});
</script>
```

Conforme dito, quando um botão for clicado, irá jogar o valor do `data-id` no input hidden que possui o `name` igual ao valor do `data-btn`. Quando o último form for submetido, irá enviar esses campos com os valores clicados pelo usuário para o backend, onde você poderá recebê-los pelo método `POST` através dos seus `name`'s.

Comment: Obrigado Sam! dessa forma consegui salvar os IDs

Answer (score 1):

Você tem que editar sua view para receber estes valores, no **flask** eu sei que tem o `request.form.ge["nome do campo"]` no **django** `nome_do_campo = request.POST.get('nome_do_campo')` Obs.: tem que ver caso o form seja POST , mas pode ser `request.GET.get('nome_do_campo')`

Comment: Marcos, coloquei os botões dentro de um form nessas abas porém não tem efeito, ele não chama a url, não sei se é pq tenho uma lógica JS que faz todo o fluxo, os botões da primeira aba levam o usuário para a segunda e assim por diante.

Comment: no django caso vá usar css e javascript tem que marcar com {% load static %} e dentro desta tag adicionar seu script js , pois sem isso ele não funciona, não pode colocar javascript sem estar dentro de uma tag do django pois ele não irá renderizar esta parte. veja se esse link te ajuda: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page

Comment: veja outro exemplo como carregar arquivos estáticos em páginas do django:https://desenvolvimentoaberto.org/2015/01/23/django-usando-javascript-python-linux/